# Access another frame with javascript in Google Chrome (Uncaught ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frame, referenceerror

I'm developing a website with a flash mp3 player on the top frame and the content down on the bottom frame as to have music playing through page changes. A song title button is pressed on the bottom frame which accesses the javascript on the top frame to trigger its flash mp3 player to play that song.

This works in IE and Firefox, but not Chrome.

This is in the top frame:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<title>m4Techno.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js">
    function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
        var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
        return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
    }
    function callToActionscript(flash, str) {
        getFlashMovie(flash).toASplaySong(str);
    }
</script>
```

The bottom frame accesses it through a button:

```
<form target="topFrame" action="javascript:callToActionscript('m4player', 'music/remixes/m4 - She\'s Lovely (160kbps).mp3')" id="form1">
```

But, when I'm in Chrome I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: callToActionscript is not defined

I can't find a solution for this! Any love?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `src` attribute from your second `<script>` element, and you should be ok:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js">
  function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  ...
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  ...
```